# how to find the set of $α ∈ R$?

Tags: linear-algebra

For each real number $α$, we define the bilinear form $F_α :R^3 \times R^3 \rightarrow R $ by

$F_α(x_1, x_2, x_3),(y_1, y_2, y_3)= 2x_1y_1 + (α + 5)x_1y_2 + x_1y_3 + (α + 5)x_2y_1
−(2α + 4)x_2y_2 + 2x_2y_3 + x_3y_1 + 2x_3y_2 + 2x_3y_3.$

Find the set of $α ∈ R$ such that $F_α$ is positive definite

Let us take

$F_α((x_1, x_2, x_3),(x_1, x_2, x_3))= 2x_1x_1 + (α + 5)x_1x_2 + x_1x_3 + (α + 5)x_2x_1 −(2α + 4)x_2x_2 + 2x_2x_3 + x_3x_1 + 2x_3x_2 + 2x_3x_3$

=$2x_1^2 + (α + 5)x_1x_2 + 2x_1x_3 + (α + 5)x_2x_1 −(2α + 4)x_2^2+   4x_3x_2 + 2x_3^2$

Now converting them into matrix   $$F_α =\begin{bmatrix} 2& α+5 &1 \\  α+ 5 &-2α+4 &  2\\ 1& 2 & 2\end{bmatrix} >0$$

Now for postive definite  :
$$F_1 =\begin{bmatrix} 2& α+5 \\  α+ 5 &-2α+4 \\ \end{bmatrix}_{2\times2} >0$$

i m getting $-α^2-14α -33 > 0$

$α^2+14α +33 <0$

$( α -(7-\sqrt 82) (α+ (7+\sqrt 82)) < 0$

$( α -(7-\sqrt 82) < 0$

$α <(7-\sqrt 82)$ or $α >-7-\sqrt 82)$

$-7-\sqrt 82 <α <7-\sqrt 82$  is the  required answer

is its corrects or not ??? Pliz check its ...and its  my  humble request...

Comment: @ancientmathematician..that  mean how can i approached this problem...  can u give me  any idea/hints/solution ???

Comment: ya @ancientmathematician  u r right,,it is typo mistake...but  tell me  that   is  my way  of doing  (my solution)  is correct or not....

Comment: You should tackle this one like the previous one, you'll get a quadratic in $\alpha$ which has to be negative and that gives you the range of possibilities.

Comment: @ancientmathematician,,,pliz check my answer whether  it is correct or nots...??

Comment: The $(2,2)$ entry should be  $-(2\alpha+4)$

Comment: .. except that's whatyou've used.

Comment: Surely the criterion you are trying to use requires the leading $1\times 1$, $2\times 2$ and $3\times 3$ minors to be positive. You seem to only be looking at the $2\times 2$ one. I think it's easiest to order the variables $x_1,x_3,x_2$ then the $1\times 1$ and $2\times 2$ are trivial and the $3\times 3$ gives a quadratic with roots $\frac{11}{2}\pm\frac{\sqrt{21}}{2}$.